# Android findAllAsync string array

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

Is there any possible way to highlight more than one term with `findAllAsync` in Java?

I have a `String[]` array with some content and want to highlight all of them in my `WebView`.

I have this void for searching:

```
public void markInBrowser(final String[] searchString) {
    browser.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(final String search: searchString) {
                browser.findAllAsync(search);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and call it from this `javaScriptInterface`:

```
private class javaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void mark() {
        String[] str = {
                "10",
                "11"
        };
        markInBrowser(str);
    }
}
```

But in my `WebView` (`browser`) only "11" gets highlighted.